# C - fprintf array to txt file in mcedit

Tags: c, arrays, output, printf

i have 2 vectors in 1 array ex.:
A: 1,2,3 -B: 4,5,6 array looks like: 1 2 3 4 5 6
 and i must print  the Dyadic product ofit to a .txt file 
but i have a problem with the printf()

```
FILE *f;
f=fopen("log.txt","w+");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=n;j<e;j++)
    {
        k++;
        fprintf(f,"%d \t",(t[i]*t[j]));
    }
fclose(f);
```

Comment: What problem(s) do you have?  What input do you provide, what output do you get/expect?

Comment: main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:47: warning: passing argument 1 of 'fprintf' from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/stdio.h:333: note: expected 'struct FILE * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'char *'
main.c:47: error: too few arguments to function 'fprintf'

Comment: If that's the case, the code you pasted is not the code you compiled. Make sure that "f" is still a FILE* when in the fprintf's scope. Your compiler thinks it's a string. Or maybe you have another fprintf where you forgot the "f" argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that somewhere in your code you have a fprintf that looks like this

```
    fprintf("format", args);
```

and you forgot the file argument:

```
    fprintf(f, "format", args);
            ^^
```